# How do I create a Graph Node Table in SQL Server using SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, graph-databases

I'm trying to create a Graph Table in SQL Server using SQLAlchemy.

SQL would be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [audit].[tableMetaData](
      [_tableMetaDataId] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
      [table] VARCHAR(200),
      [createdDateTime] DATETIME,
      [loadType] VARCHAR(200),
      [loadBy] VARCHAR(200),
      [description] VARCHAR(MAX),
) AS NODE;
```

I can create a standard table with SQL Alchemy using the following:

```
auditMeta = MetaData()
tableMetaData = Table(
    'tableMetaData', auditMeta,
    Column('_tableMetaDataId', INTEGER, primary_key = True),
    Column('table', VARCHAR(200)),
    Column('createdDateTime', DATETIME),
    Column('loadType', VARCHAR(200)),
    Column('loadBy', VARCHAR(200)),
    Column('description', VARCHAR(None)),
    schema = auditSchema
)

auditMeta.create_all(auditEngine)
```

How do I add the 'AS NODE' component into the SQL Alchemy code to let SQL Server know that this is a Graph table?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: nit pick: table (object) names are of type `sysname` which is [functionally equivalent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql#remarks) to `nvarchar(128) not null`.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning. The table column contains [dbName].[schemaName].[tableName]. I've just named it table for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the default compilation of `CreateTable` construct

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles


auditMeta = MetaData()
tableMetaData = Table(
    'tableMetaData', auditMeta,
    Column('_tableMetaDataId', INTEGER, primary_key = True),
    Column('table', VARCHAR(200)),
    Column('createdDateTime', DATETIME),
    Column('loadType', VARCHAR(200)),
    Column('loadBy', VARCHAR(200)),
    Column('description', VARCHAR(None)),
    schema = auditSchema,
    info={'as_node': True}
)


@compiles(CreateTable)
def create_as_node(create_table, compiler, **kw):
    if create_table.element.info.get('as_node'):
        compiler.post_create_table = lambda x: ' AS NODE'
    return compiler.visit_create_table(create_table, **kw)


auditMeta.create_all(auditEngine)
```

see more in [Custom SQL Constructs and Compilation Extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/compiler.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.compiler)